# parameter is not valid when loading image from database after updating the image with text on it in c#

Tags: c#, sql, image, parameters, bitmap

I have a student table with one image field which is student ID, student id created by putting student information on the png file and save in the database 
this is code for putting text on the image file and save it in the database and it is working correctly

```
byte[] pic=null;
//call the idcard image
    Bitmap bitMapImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(@"C:\Users\pary\Videos\login2\login\image\card.png");
Graphics graphicImage = Graphics.FromImage(bitMapImage);
graphicImage.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
graphicImage.DrawString(TxtNamestudent.Text,
  new Font("Arial", 10),
        SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(1500, 555));
graphicImage.DrawString(comdep.SelectedItem.ToString(),
   new Font("Arial", 10),
        SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(1550, 690));
graphicImage.DrawString(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"),
   new Font("Arial", 10),
       SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(1250, 850));
graphicImage.DrawString(cmbBloodgroup.SelectedItem.ToString(),
   new Font("Arial", 10),
      SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(1780, 960));
graphicImage.DrawString(dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"),
   new Font("Arial", 10),
        SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(1300, 1100));
OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";
// if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
//{
// display image in picture box
//  Image secondimage = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
// Image bimap2 = ResizeImage(secondimage, 70, 100);
//Bitmap bimap2 = new Bitmap(secondimage, new Size(12, 15));
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitMapImage))
{
    //draw other image on top of main Image
    g.DrawImage(bimap2, new Point(170, 600));
     final = ResizeImage(bitMapImage, 500, 400);
    //save new image
     final.Save(@"C:\Users\pary\Videos\login2\login\image" + TxtNamestudent.Text + ".Jpg");
    pictureBox2.Image = final;
    pictureBox2.Height = final.Height;
    pictureBox2.Width = final.Width;
    imglocation = (@"C:\Users\pary\Videos\login2\login\image" + TxtNamestudent.Text + ".Jpg");
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(imglocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    pic = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
    //MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    //pic = stream.ToArray();

}

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\pary\Videos\login2\login\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
//open the connetion
con.Open();
//write query

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Table4 (KurdName,EnglishName,Blood,Gender,Sale_Ladaekbwn,Sale_Darchun,PhoneNumber,Email,Qonax,Schul,Department,pic)
VALUES (N'" + TxtNamestudent.Text + "','" + Txtname.Text + "','" + cmbBloodgroup.SelectedItem.ToString() + "',N'" + Gender + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "','" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "','" + textmobil.Text + "','" + TxtEmail.Text + "',N'" + combqonax.SelectedItem.ToString() + "',N'" + comskul.SelectedItem.ToString() + "',N'" + comdep.SelectedItem.ToString() + "', @pic )", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pic", pic);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

and this is the code for loading the image and put it on the picturebox and it is also working without errors

```
string date_birth = (myreader["Sale_Ladaekbwn"].ToString());
string date_issue = (myreader["Sale_Darchun"].ToString());
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse(date_birth);
DateTime date2 = DateTime.Parse(date_issue);
dateTimePicker1.Value = date1;
dateTimePicker2.Value = date2;
byte[] data = new byte[0];
data = (Byte[])(myreader["pic"]);

MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data);
//mem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
// Bitmap img = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mem);
mem.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
mem.Position = 0;
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(mem);
pictureBox2.Image= Image.FromStream(mem);
pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
mem.Close();
```

the code above is working and it is loading the image from database and put it in picturebox

the problem I have is when I am trying to update the image and information stored in the database, this is the code for updating id image in the database

```
private void btn_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    byte[] pic = null;
    //call the idcard image
    Bitmap bitMapImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(@"C:\Users\pary\Videos\login2\login\image\card.png");
    Graphics graphicImage = Graphics.FromImage(bitMapImage);
    graphicImage.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    graphicImage.DrawString(TxtNamestudent.Text,
       new Font("Arial", 10),
             SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(1450, 555));
    graphicImage.DrawString(comdep.SelectedItem.ToString(),
        new Font("Arial", 10),
             SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(1550, 690));
    graphicImage.DrawString(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"),
       new Font("Arial", 10),
           SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(1200, 850));
    graphicImage.DrawString(cmbBloodgroup.SelectedItem.ToString(),
       new Font("Arial", 10),
          SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(1780, 960));
    graphicImage.DrawString(dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"),
        new Font("Arial", 10),
             SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(1300, 1100));
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";
    // if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    //{
    // display image in picture box
    //  Image secondimage = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
    // Image bimap2 = ResizeImage(secondimage, 70, 100);
    //Bitmap bimap2 = new Bitmap(secondimage, new Size(12, 15));
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitMapImage))
    {
        //draw other image on top of main Image
        g.DrawImage(bimap2, new Point(170, 600));
        final = ResizeImage(bitMapImage, 500, 400);
        //save new image
        final.Save(@"C:\Users\pary\Videos\login2\login\image"+ TxtNamestudent.Text + ".Jpg");
        pictureBox2.Image = final;
        pictureBox2.Height = final.Height;
        pictureBox2.Width = final.Width;
        imglocation = (@"C:\Users\pary\Videos\login2\login\image" + TxtNamestudent.Text + ".Jpg");
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(imglocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        pic = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
        //MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        //pic = stream.ToArray();
    }




    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\pary\Videos\login2\login\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"update Table4 set KurdName=
          N'" + TxtNamestudent.Text + "',EnglishName='" + Txtname.Text + "',Blood='" + cmbBloodgroup.SelectedItem.ToString() + "',Gender=N'" + Gender + "',Sale_Ladaekbwn='" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "',Sale_Darchun='" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "',PhoneNumber='" + textmobil.Text + "',Email='" + TxtEmail.Text + "',Qonax=N'" + combqonax.SelectedItem.ToString() + "',Schul=N'" + comskul.SelectedItem.ToString() + "',Department=N'" + comdep.SelectedItem.ToString() + "',pic='" + pic + "'  where( ID='" + numVal + "')", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pic", pic);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```

this code is updating information on the id image and save it. The problem occurs I am trying to load the image after updating, it gives me "parameter is not valid" exception. I used the same code for the loading the image.

```
string date_birth = (myreader["Sale_Ladaekbwn"].ToString());
string date_issue = (myreader["Sale_Darchun"].ToString());
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse(date_birth);
DateTime date2 = DateTime.Parse(date_issue);
dateTimePicker1.Value = date1;
dateTimePicker2.Value = date2;
byte[] data = new byte[0];
data = (Byte[])(myreader["pic"]);

MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data);
mem.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
mem.Position = 0;
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(mem);
pictureBox2.Image= Image.FromStream(mem);
pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
mem.Close();
```

it gives me error in the line " Bitmap bmp= new Bitmap(mem);

please if anybody has any idea please let me know I really appreciated it, I have viva next week. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can likely make the entire issue moot by using query parameters instead of trying to manually build the query like that.  ADO .NET should be able to handle a `byte[]` as a parameter for a binary column.  As an added bonus, you'd be protecting against SQL injection, to which your current code is *wide open*.

Comment: David thanks,  I am not very good at C# that  all I can do, can you help out to fix it, I appreciate your help.

Comment: MSDN has some helpful articles on the subject: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254953(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Your code is very bulky. "new MemoryStream(data)" will load the data in the stream already. The "mem.Write(..)" and "mem.Position=0" are not needed. Did you debug your code and looked at the contents of data?

Comment: @JeroenHeier thanks, no I haven't done it cause I don't know how to do it but it gives me the error in the line Bitmap bmp=new Bitmap(mem)

Comment: You can set a breakpoint in the Visual Studio editor by clicking on the left-hand vertical bar (a red dot is displayed) and using F5. Hover above data and inspect its length and contents (should contain non zero's and length > 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume simple matter is here like "',pic='" + pic + "' should be corrected like "', pic= @pic where ID='" + numVal + "'", con);

And that's why it's not updated correctly. Check your UPDATE command syntax carefully and please try if it works..

As last, you're using dynamic query which is susceptible against SQL Injection attack advised by David as above.

Therefore, after the first applying above simple correction succeeds, for the future, you'd better to consider parameterized query, for example as below,
A DataType of Parameters is better to be defined specifically as well.

If your problem is solved, please mark as answer.

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
comm.Connection = conn;
comm.CommandText = "UPDATE Table4 SET KurdName= @k_KurdName, pic= @k_pic  WHERE Id= @k_Id";

var da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@k_KurdName", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
da.SelectCommand.Parameters["@k_KurdName"].Value = TxtNamestudent.Text;
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@k_pic", SqlDbType.Binary));
da.SelectCommand.Parameters["@k_pic"].Value = pic;
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@k_Id", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
da.SelectCommand.Parameters["@k_Id"].Value = numval;
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion is it not working, it gives me the same error " parameter is not valid"., any  idea what cause the problem?

Comment: Oh, I see. Please just try this. I'm sure this work ! comdep.SelectedItem.ToString() + "',pic= @pic where

Comment: In syntax rule, every '"+ yourtext +"' means dynamic query. but <pic=   @pic> is not dynamic query but more secure parameterized query. Before <pic= @pic>, they're all dynamic but only the part <pic= @pic> is not dynamic. I added <> just because stackoverflow doesn't allow many @ character in comment. Please ignore it. You have to understand and better change later for the future...If this is solved, please mark as answer. I'll appreciate it.

Comment: And see your UPDATE command syntax, there's no parameter with @ character, but you're adding with parameter.Add command just below that..Think about it..

Comment: I have tried it is the same, you know for the insert command it is working perfectly but I don't know why after updating data in database it gives me this error. and update is working and all the information changing correctly. but the problem occurs when loading image after update.

Comment: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Table4 set KurdName=
          N'"+TxtNamestudent.Text+"',EnglishName='"+Txtname.Text+ "',Blood='"+cmbBloodgroup.SelectedItem.ToString()+"',Gender=N'"+ Gender+"',Sale_Ladaekbwn='"+ dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")+"',Sale_Darchun='"+ dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")+"',PhoneNumber='"+ textmobil.Text+ "',Email='" +TxtEmail.Text+ "',Qonax=N'" + combqonax.SelectedItem.ToString() + "',Schul=N'" + comskul.SelectedItem.ToString() + "',Department=N'" + comdep.SelectedItem.ToString() + "', pic= @pic  where  ID='" + numVal + "'", con);

Comment: Just copy right above comment and replace with your old one. Please try if it works..If you look into your INSERT command there's a @pic parameter. That's the difference.

Comment: And there should be no () after WHERE. Please try above comment. I deleted () after WHERE as well.

Comment: I removed () as you said, still the same, the problem is with the image when loading. the error is in this line Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(mem);

Comment: Did you just copy my above comment? If update is done abnormally, the original image doesn't exist any more.

Comment: oh, congratulations !  Utilize google to research with good keyword. There're many examples. If you mark my answer, I'll appreciate much. Have nice day !

Comment: I'll appreciate if you compensate and respect other's efforts. Some people who just started stackoverflow don't know sometimes.

Comment: dear @Kay Lee, I tried to mark your answer, but unfortunately stackoverflow didn't allow me, they said "you need total reputation of 15". That is the reason I'm so sorry.

Comment: @Thinker, I upvoted your question and your reputation should be now 18. Could you please try? I didn't know like you before :) let's make good program !